# Energy-efficient Power Supply (PSU) circuit for STM32WLE Microcontroller with 1.8-3.6V for 150mA peak current

Tags: microcontroller, power, circuit-design, power-electronics, low-power

I am thinking how to best (best=lowest energy consumption and standby current) power a STM32WLE:
https://www.st.com/en/microcontrollers-microprocessors/stm32wlex.html

The power management of the IC itself is described on p23 onwards, the MCU accepts from 1.8-3.6V.

My constraints are:

- I want to power an external hall effect sensor with a stable voltage (let's say 3.3V).
- As battery, I would like to use a LiPo but it is not a must.
- Standby current should be less than 50µA
- Max current pulled will be 200mA

I have been thinking about following implementations:

1. Texas is offering a few nice buck or buck/boost converters such as these ones here: https://www.powerelectronicsnews.com/diy-how-build-a-smart-power-supply-for-your-microcontroller-projects/ . If I use a buck/bost converter, I am not so limited to the battery chemistry. What do you think?
2. Here someone has tried using just a couple of forward biased silicon diodes to reduce a 5V input signal but it just seems wrong when going for lowest power consumption: https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/technical-articles/a-low-cost-method-of-powering-a-microcontroller/
3. Previous thread here from stackexchange:
   [Most efficient way to convert from 3.5-4.2V (singe cell LiPo) to stable 3.3V for currents up to 500 mA?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/458872/most-efficient-way-to-convert-from-3-5-4-2v-singe-cell-lipo-to-stable-3-3v-for)
   Buck converters are suggested there
4. The LTC3440 has a  quiescent current of around 25µA, which sounds fair: https://www.analog.com/en/technical-articles/it-just-got-easier-to-convert-lithium-ion-battery-voltage-to-33v.html#
5. I guess I can just browse for low-quiescent current buck/boost converters.

EDIT: My question is: Can you review my ideas for implementing an energy-efficient power supply for a microcontroller?

Comment: @Transistor Alright, edited it.